# Apply item replacement inside enumerate in Perl regex?

Tags: regular-expression, perl

Data

```
7. Masi is the same as
\begin{enumerate}
A
B
ABC ha lorem
\end{enumerate}

1. ABC is
\begin{enumerate}
P
B
Lorem maam
\end{enumerate}
```

which I want to be

```
7. Masi is the same as
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item ABC ha lorem
\end{enumerate}

1. ABC is
\begin{enumerate}
\item P
\item B
\item Lorem maam
\end{enumerate}
```

My startup regex is based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126293/16920)

> ```
> perl -000pe
> s/\n/\n\\begin{enumerate}\n [A-Za-z1-9]* \end{enumerate}/
> ... [problem here!]
> masi.tex
> ```

where

- -000 : activate Perl's paragraph mode, this causes "lines" to be defined by two consecutive newlines (\n\n), so that each of your questions is treated as a single line.
- -pe : read each line of the input file and print it (-p) after applying the script passed as -e.

I want to replace the beginning of each new line inside the match with `\item`.
My pseudocode for **problem here code**

> s/\n/\item /g

to apply things inside enumerate environment.

How

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer on your previous question. Accepting your own is fine and there is no reason to make it community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ue the `..` or [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator to confine substitutions to the begin/end sections:

```
while (<DATA>) {
   if ( /\\begin/ .. /\\end/ ) {
       s/^(?!\\)/\\item /;  
   }
   print;
}

__DATA__
7. Masi is the same as
\begin{enumerate}
A
B
ABC ha lorem
\end{enumerate}

1. ABC is
\begin{enumerate}
P
B
Lorem maam
\end{enumerat
```

If you prefer a command-line script:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\\begin/../\\end/) {s/^(?!\\)/\\item /};print'
```

Or, shorter with an implicit `print`:

```
perl -pe 'if (/\\begin/../\\end/) {s/^(?!\\)/\\item /}'
```

The `(?!...)` is a negative look-ahead assertion.

Comment: your first perl command fails to add `\item` before A,B,P.

Answer (score 3):

Another `Perl` solution:

```
$ perl -pe '
    if (/\\begin/../\\end/) {
        next if /\\begin/ || /\\end/;
        s/^/\\item /;
    }
' file
7. Masi is the same as
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item ABC ha lorem
\end{enumerate}

1. ABC is
\begin{enumerate}
\item P
\item B
\item Lorem maam
\end{enumerate}
```

**Explanation**

- `if (/\\begin/../\\end/)`: our lines delimiter start with `\begin` and end with `\end`.
- `next if /\\begin/ || /\\end/`: we don't need start and end, skip them.
- `s/^/\\item /`: we replace start of each lines with our desired pattern.
- `-p` option causes `perl` print each lines after we processed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag. Set it to 1 when entering enumerate, clear it on the end. Insert item when the flag is set:

```
perl -pe '$inside = 0 if /\\end{enumerate}/;
          print "\\item " if $inside;
          $inside = 1 if /\\begin{enumerate}/;
         ' input.tex
```

Note that I check the end before printing so the `\item` is not prepended to the end line.